# Es update giving bad request

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to update the following document:

```
$ curl http://192.168.0.108:9200/customer/customer/AVGbTCQ2XioLLLZULBAD?pretty
{
  "_index" : "customer",
  "_type" : "customer",
  "_id" : "AVGbTCQ2XioLLLZULBAD",
  "_version" : 15,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"age":0,"n":"Abhishek Gupta","id":"AVGbTCQ2XioLLLZULBAD"}
}
```

According to [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates) my update request is:

```
$ curl -XPOST http://192.168.0.108:9200/customer/customer/AVGbTCQ2XioLLLZULBAD/_update -d '{
>   "script": {
>     "inline": "ctx._source.n = name",
>     "params": {
>       "name": "Elas"
>     }
>   }
> }'
{"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;]","status":400}
```

Why I am getting bad request?

Es version details:

```
$ curl http://192.168.0.108:9200/
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Vance Astro",
  "cluster_name" : "dexter-elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.1",
    "build_hash" : "b88f43fc40b0bcd7f173a1f9ee2e97816de80b19",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-07-29T09:54:16Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scripted updated in ES 1.7.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates) is slightly different than in ES 2.x, i.e. there is no [`inline` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates) like in ES 2.x, instead you write it like this:

```
curl -XPOST http://192.168.0.108:9200/customer/customer/AVGbTCQ2XioLLLZULBAD/_update -d '{
    "script": "ctx._source.n = name",
    "params": {
      "name": "Elas"
    }
}'
```

Comment: Then its error on their documentation, as I was looking at current docs
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates

Comment: It's not an error, the `.../current/...` docs is always for the latest version (right now 2.1). If you have ES 1.7, you need to pick the docs for the version 1.7 in the selector.